# swift: Elegant Way to Map Optional to Array

Tags: swift

I am looking for an elegant way to map an `Optional` to an `Array`. What I mean by that is the following:

- If the `Optional` is `.none`, return an empty `Array<Wrapped>`
- If the `Optional` is `.some`, return a single element `Array<Wrapped>`

Now this can be done like this

```
let seq = value.map { [$0] } ?? []
```

Unfortunately this gets quite ugly and illegible when you want to use it inline.

Is there a better method to accomplish this, without writing a `extension`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting your optional in an array, and `compactMap` that array with the identity function?

```
[yourOptional].compactMap { $0 }
```

As Martin R suggested, you can use `CollectionOfOne` to save the creation of a throwaway array, at the cost of writing a few more characters:

```
CollectionOfOne(yourOptional).compactMap { $0 }
```

Comment: True, its a bit less messy :)

Comment: @ErikAigner Judging by the way you phrased it, I was kinda expecting a "but..." there. No? "But not clean enough?"

Comment: A minor variant is `CollectionOfOne(yourOptional).compactMap { $0 }` which avoids the creation of a temporary array.

Comment: @MartinR I didn't know that existed! I would have thought Swift would be smart enough to optimise constant one-element arrays to something like that...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better method to accomplish this, without writing a extension?

No. The method you're looking for still hasn't made its way into the Swift Standard Library.

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Create a single-element array literal, or an empty one.
  /// - Returns: `[self!]` if `.some`; `[]` if `nil`.
  /// - Note: This cannot be generalized to all types,
  /// as Swift doesn't employ  universal non-optional defaults.
  func compacted<ExpressibleByArrayLiteral: Swift.ExpressibleByArrayLiteral>() -> ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
  where ExpressibleByArrayLiteral.ArrayLiteralElement == Wrapped {
    .init(compacting: self)
  }
}
```

```swift
// MARK: - ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
public extension ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
  /// Create a single-element array literal, or an empty one.
  /// - Returns: `[optional!]` if `.some`; `[]` if `nil`.
  /// - Note: This cannot be generalized to all types,
  /// as Swift doesn't employ  universal non-optional defaults.
  init(compacting optional: ArrayLiteralElement?) {
    self = optional.map { [$0] } ?? []
  }
}
```

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(
  [""],
  ("" as Optional).compacted()
)

XCTAssertEqual(
  Set(),
  Int?.none.compacted()
)
```

*C# is an example of a language with "[universal non-optional defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default)".*

---

[NSPointerArray has the argument-less `compact`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspointerarray/1413659-compact), which is a similar concept, and the inspiration for the first half of the  `compactMap` that does exist in the standard library. [It's now available as `compacted`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Compacted.md).